# On Authentication for google contacts, Callback from google returned in a new session

Tags: google-app-engine, gdata-api, gdata

I am using GAE + GWT + Guice , Doing following for Google contacts API. (see code)

When Google service redirects back to application URL with Token, 
it creates new session, as URL was called from Google server not client's browser.

**Two questions**
1. Is it correct behavior? If not, How can I correct it?
2. What is the preferred way to store/use token for requesting user?

**Request Servlet (GWT RPC)**

```
public String getAuthLink() {
    String next = "http://localhost:8888/serviceCallback?service=GMAIL";
    String scope = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/";
    boolean secure = false;
    boolean session = true;
    return AuthSubUtil.getRequestUrl(next, scope, secure, session);
}

@Override
public boolean isAuthenticated(ServiceProviderKey serviceProviderKey) {
    //SESSION PRINT A
    System.out.println("Session: " + getThreadLocalRequest().getSession().getId()); 
    //SOME CODE
}
```

**Callback servlet**

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
        String authToken = req.getParameter("token");
        String sessionToken = AuthSubUtil.exchangeForSessionToken(authToken, null);
            //SESSION PRINT B
        System.out.println("Session: " + req.getSession().getId());
        req.getSession().setAttribute("token", sessionToken);
}
```

### EDIT

I understood that receiving different session is correct behavior, so now  I want to figure out, for which user (session in my app) I have received callback for. so I though of passing session_id/user_id to callback_uri but it is not allowed, callback URI must match with registered callback URI in Google API console. I am really stuck.. Looks like only I am having this particular issue, Any idea?